# for item in list or in sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a list which may or may not include further sublists. I need to run a block of code for every item in the list, and for every item in any sublists in the list. This is what my `for` statement looks like right now:

```py
for item in mylist:
    ...
```

What is the most efficient way to rewrite that so `item` is never one of the sublists, and so that the code will run once for every item in all of the sublist, in addition to every item in the list?

Comment: if you will have code in functon `your_function` then you can use recursion - `for item in data: if isinstance(item, list): your_function(item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general ways to do this, either recursively:

```py
def unroll_recursive(lst):
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            yield from unroll_recursive(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

Or iteratively

```py
from collections import deque
def unroll_iterative(lst)
    q = deque(lst)
    while q:
        el = q.popleft()
        if isinstance(el, list):
            q.extend(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

Comment: small typo - it should be `from unroll_recursive(el)` instead of `from unroll(el)`

Comment: It seems that one level of flattening is enough for the original question. In that case, you can simply `yield from el` in the `unroll_recursive` method.